# Swift regex for characters and empty spaces

Tags: regex, swift

I'm trying a regex expression to only allow characters and spaces for a full name field i.e. Mr Bob Smith

What I've currently tried:

```
let textRegex = "[A-Za-z+\\s]"
let textRegex = "[A-Za-z ]"
let textRegex = "[A-Za-z+ ]"
let textRegex = "([A-Za-z ])"
```

It doesn't appear to be working.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe `let textRegex = "^[\\s\\p{L}]+$"` will work? What do you mean by "doesn't appear to be working"?

Comment: Testing the field by entering a full name

Comment: This solved my issue though. Thanks!

Comment: Does the solution below work, too?

Comment: Yes the below solution also works and looks the same as my other regex's. Thanks

Comment: Then please upvote and accept.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your regular expression isn't working because you misplaced the + symbol.

This one will work:

```
([A-Za-z ]+)
```

I don't know how Swift handles regex however so keep in mind if you strictly want whitespaces only, it is better to just add " " character instead of the \s which can sometimes be extended to other spaces.